# Creating a logical volume and mounting to a directory

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

I am new in scripting wold, therefore I need your kindly help.
I am writing a script which should create a logical volume and mount it to a directory. But my code shows some errors and I don't know why.

```
#!/bin/bash

ls /home
echo "Where would you like to mount the logical Valume? Choose a directory please!"
read path

lvcreate -L 2G -n lvHolla fedora_localhost-live

mkfs -t ext3 /dev/fedora_localhost-live/lvHolla

ls /home/
cd
mount -t ext3 /dev/fedora_localhost-live/lvHolla /home/"$path"
```

The errors I get:

1. ```
   Volume group "fedora_localhost-live" has insufficient free space (0 extents): 512 required. mke2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
   ```
2. ```
   The file /dev/fedora_localhost-live/lvHolla does not exist and no size was specified
   ```
3. ```
   mount: /home/naseer: special device /dev/fedora_localhost-live/lvHolla does not exist
   ```

I know, no enough free space, therefore the first error. But why the 2th & 3th?

Thanks a lot for your gently feedback and correcting my mistake!

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: First try creating a script without interactive input. I don't do interactive input in bash, but what you have looks unlikely to be correct. First try testing your interactive input with a simple script that just echoes input. And if you have a problem, always show all output, including errors. Also ext3 is no longer commonly used. I think the default these days is ext4. And the second `ls /home/` appears to be redundant.

Comment: Your script should work, _if_ you run it as root, the `$path` directory exists, it has has a simple name (e.g. does not start/end with spaces), nothing is already mounted on `/home/"$path"`, your volume group is named `fedora_localhost-live` and has more than 2 GB of free space... So, it is essential that you also share the error message(s) you see. Please, [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/607083/edit) them into your question.

Comment: thank you all! of course i run the script as the super user! it is clear, that i don't have enough free space, therefore the  error 1.
i know,  no enough free space, therefore the first error.
error 1: Volume group "fedora_localhost-live" has insufficient free space (0 extents): 512 required.
mke2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
error 2: The file /dev/fedora_localhost-live/lvHolla does not exist and no size was specified.
error 3: mount: /home/naseer: special device /dev/fedora_localhost-live/lvHolla does not exist.

why 2th & 3th error? Perhaps does not exist anything, right?

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your question, adding the errors from your comment to it. Note that comments are basically meant for asking for clarifications and are not meant to stay, all the relevant information should be in the question text. Feel free to further edit it if you see room for improvement.

Comment: thanks a lot guys, you all helped me really a lot to learn something new today! sadly i can't do more than an appreciation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems from the first error, that your volume group does not have enough free space.

What is the output from

```
vgdisplay fedora_localhost-live
```

In order for your script to work, the row stating "Free  PE / Size" should be bigger than the logical volume you are trying to create with the script.

Something like this:

```
--- Volume group ---
  VG Name               fedora_localhost-live
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        3
  Metadata Sequence No  11
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                3
  Act PV                3
  VG Size               51.42 GB
  PE Size               4.00 MB
  Total PE              13164
  Alloc PE / Size       13 / 52.00 MB
  Free  PE / Size       13151 / 51.37 GB
  VG UUID               jxQJ0a-ZKk0-OpMO-0118-nlwO-wwqd-fD5D32
```

For reference https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/logical_volume_manager_administration/vg_display

Since, you are getting the first error, you will get the following 2 errors as you described in your question. They are related to the first problem. I'll put my money on, that if you fix the free space issue, the other two problems will go away, since, the logical volume is not created, the `mkfs` can not to it's job, since it will not format a folder location.
And since there is no block device, then it cannot mount it.